# Two different covariance return for same formula in R

Tags: r, covariance

I was confused by covariance in R. 
When I use E(x*y)-E(x)E(y), it returns a different value for cov().
Can you help me to understand it?
my code:

```
spot<- c(0.5,0.61,-0.22,-0.35,0.79,0.04,0.15,0.7,-0.51,-0.41)
future<- c(0.56,0.63,-0.12,-0.44,0.6,-0.06,0.01,0.8,-0.56,-0.46)
ms<-mean(spot)
mf<-mean(future)
msf<-mean(spot*future)
cov<- msf-mf*ms

#the way above is wrong for giving  0.22272 while cov gives 0.2474667
covr<- cov(spot,future)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you used the correct formula. The formula for covariance between two vectors `X` and `Y` each of length `n` is:

```
cov(X,Y) = sigma((X-mean(X))*(Y-mean(Y)))/(n-1)


spot<- c(0.5,0.61,-0.22,-0.35,0.79,0.04,0.15,0.7,-0.51,-0.41)
future<- c(0.56,0.63,-0.12,-0.44,0.6,-0.06,0.01,0.8,-0.56,-0.46)
covar = sum((spot-mean(spot))*(future-mean(future)))/(length(spot)-1)
#covar
#0.2474667
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But in wiki, [link] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance 'By using the linearity property of expectations, this can be simplified to the expected value of their product minus the product of their expected values' turn to the formula E(xy)-E(x)E(y). When i used it, it returned the false value, how it happened?

Comment: @EllieZhang Apologies. I don't think I can satisfactorily answer your question. You should post this on stats.stackexchange.com. If you do post, please share the link to your question with me in the comments here.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/330657/two-different-covariance-return-for-same-formula-in-r